# Place API for Android

Tags: android, google-places-api

I'm trying to use the Google Places API in my application. For that I need to generate Server Key.

I used my device IP address to generate a Server Key. My app works only in my device. If I use some other device I get an error:

```
{
   "error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key.",
   "predictions" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

Could you please help me in this regards. How to generate Server key which works for all devices.

Comment: i dont know  exactly but might be there is an option for allowing all ip address..can you post screen shot of your console (where you have created server key)?

Answer (score 4):

Try to create a new Places API key. When creating the key **choose the server but leave the IP field blank** (so as to allow any IP address).
Notify and vote up if it works.