# Get nearest Location from google map api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to retrieve the nearest location to a latitude and longitude.

If I perform a get with the following url

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false&key=MY_KEY`

I am expecting it to return a JSON array.

However, I get an Access Denied result. I generated my key from the Google console.

Please let me know what I might be doing wrong.

Comment: create browser key and on Google Maps Geolocation API from Google Console

Comment: REQUEST_DENIED
 This API project is not authorized to use this API. Please ensure that this API is activated in the APIs Console: Learn more: https://code.google.com/apis/console


i got above Error

Comment: Did you switch ON Google Maps Geolocation API from Google Console? If not please give a try. Check this as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24864687/place-api-for-android

Comment: thanks for us replay i just activated "Google Maps JavaScript API v3"
can u please let me know what all services i need to activate ??

Answer (score 1):

For retrieving the current location of device you can go-through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145089/what-is-the-simplest-and-most-robust-way-to-get-the-users-current-location-in-a/3145655#3145655) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428209/show-current-location-and-nearby-places-and-route-between-two-places-using-googl).

Then get places near your location using [Google's Place API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/) and you can also refer [this blog](http://ddewaele.blogspot.com/2011/05/introducing-google-places-api.html).